# What Does FFmpeg Exit Code -1073741819 Mean?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg 4.2.2 on Windows to mix two audio tracks, however the filter I am using is causing FFmpeg to crash:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -filter_complex asplit[a][b];[a]amix[c];[c][b]acrossfade 3.wav
```

After running the command FFmpeg hangs for a couple of seconds then closes. Using `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` shows the error code is -1073741819, but I can't seem to find anything on what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1073741819` is `ffffffffc0000005` so it's an Access Violation Windows exception.

Comment: It turns out it was a bug in the release version I was using which had already been fixed in the daily builds. Upgrading to the latest daily build fixed the problem.